# Plotting a simple line between two points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a simple line as show in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z005s.png).

Here is what I tried but failed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,10,100,1000,10000]
y = [1,10**(-1),10**(-2),10**(-3),10**(-4)] 
plt.plot(x, y,'gray',linestyle='--',marker='')
```

This code gives me very odd output. I need to make it same as in the figure.

I don't have all data points beside I only have those numbers in figure that I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you just want to plot 2 lines between 2 points, you only need 4 data points to plot this.  However, to get the display you desire, there are several other tricks we need to apply here:

***Plotting Data***

```
x1 = [1, 100]
x2 = [1, 10**4]    
ys = [1, 10**-4]
```

The key is setting our axes to scale logarithmically, and setting our own labels for what should be displayed:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, ys, 'gray', linestyle=':', marker='')
ax.plot(x2, ys, 'black', linestyle='--', marker='')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000])
ax.set_yticks([10**-4, 10**-3, 10**-2, 10**-1, 10**0, 10**1])
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().labelOnlyBase = False
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().labelOnlyBase = False
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]